# Ubuntu won't boot after I installed a ssd

Tags: gui, gdm, 23.10

I just got a ssd(sda2) installed, before that I was having Ubuntu in hdd(sdb1). I just loaded Ubuntu 23.10 using a USB and it worked fine, I deleted my hdd partition and remade another partition in hdd but after I shut it down it won't boot even from bios. It gets stuck on a black terminal through which I can access my file system inside a snap dir.

What do I do to make it boot normally?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was gdm3, I just did

```
sudo apt purge gdm3 && sudo apt install gdm3 -y
```